# Why is my website loading so slow

Tags: performance, web, loading

This is the page of the website that I'm coding : http://davidcocciante.com/beta4/

The issue is that the loading page lasts 9-12 seconds. I don't have very heavy stuff. Maybe the scripts are the issue?

Thanks to you!

Comment: This might be helpful.http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/b7qFlK/http://davidcocciante.com/beta4/

Answer (score 0):

Your images are of extreme high quality, you need to optimize them for the web. There is at least 4MB and I didn't check all the images on the site.

This slows down the load time so much, if users are on the mobile device it will take even longer to load.

The only solution to this that I can think of is to optimize ALL images for web using Photoshop or what ever you decide to go with.

Best of luck, website looks nice however graphic weight OVERLOAD :)

Comment: Ok thanks! I already made an optimising pass on my images. But it's the PNGs that weight a lot. I'll keep optimising then!